# Issue sending the row selected to another viewcontroller using notification observer | Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Essentially I am trying to send the value of the tableView row selected to another ViewController using Notifications. But for some reason, nothing is being passed to the second controller.

In the TableViewController I select the value of the row selected by doing this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


    let portfolio = structure[indexPath.row]
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("selectedTOCustomer"), object: nil, userInfo: ["TOCustomerKey": portfolio])
}
```

Next, I go to another view controller and add an observer in the ViewDidLoad:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.myFunc2(notification:)), name: Notification.Name("selectedTOCustomer"), object: nil)
```

The function it is referring to is the following, it is supposed to print the value of the row selected in the second ViewController:

```
@objc func myFunc2(notification: Notification) {

    guard let data = notification.userInfo as? [String: String] else {
        return
    }
    print("\(data["TOCustomerKey"])")

}
```

UPDATE:

TableView rows are populated from JSON data structure is a variable at the top of the first view controller and references

```
var structure = [AlreadyScheduledStructure]()
```

The structure is consists of

```
struct AlreadyScheduledStructure: Codable {
    let person: String

}
```

Comment: What is `structure`?

Comment: *"Next, I go to another view controller and add an observer..."* -- if you have already posted the notification ***before*** going to the next VC, you're too late. More likely you want to save the value from `didSelectRowAt` and send it to (set it as a property) of the next VC when you "go to it."

Comment: @matt Please see my update

Comment: @DonMag Oh I see, how can the value be saved?

Comment: @DonMag you there?

Comment: @RelsonJames - *how* you are "going to another view controller"? Using a Segue? Pushing it onto a navigation controller stack? Presenting it?

Comment: I am pushing it into a navigation controller stack

Comment: @RelsonJames - ok... do a google search for `swift pass data to view controller` -- you'll get lots and lots of results with tutorials, explanations, etc.

Comment: The issue with that is I need the value of the row to be available to not just that view controller but to a bunch of other.

Comment: you could use a singleton or save in appDelegate, but appDelegate is not recomended as good practice. so my personal recomendation is that you use wth really care a singleton, also you could pass the strign every time you navigate to a new viewcontroller you need,  with any technich you need could segue o presenting.

Comment: Can you please show me an example of how I could implement a singleton, I would really appreciate it!

Comment: @kjoe I will mark your answer as correct

Comment: man but that not the answer to your question. that would be a cheat to the SO comunity make a question about how to use singleton because you make this question about sending a notification not singleton

Comment: Ok I will create a new post in a bit, but I would really appreciate your help